# Umbraco 7 - Redirecting to another page from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco

I am working with Umbraco 7 and with Umbraco for the first time. I am trying to redirect to another page from a custom controller that implements RenderMvcController.

I have tried ASP.NET MVC's `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`, but this does not seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See below code, it will redirect to `retrunUrl` page.

```
 return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using the RedirectResult class, where you can control if it should be a temporary (302) or a permanent (301) redirect:

```
return new RedirectResult("http://stackoverflow.com/", false); // 302
```